# Read from excel using StyleFrame

Tags: python, pandas, styleframe

```
sf = sf[[col for col in sf.columns
         if col.style.fill.fgColor.rgb in ('FFFFFFFF', utils.colors.white)]]
```

I got an error when read the file and looping the columns

```
return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

I want to read the excel without loosing the style values

Comment: what does the code in the question have to do with Excel?

Comment: Can you please provide the output of `import StyleFrame ; print(StyleFrame._versions_)` ?

Comment: Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
pandas 0.19.0
openpyxl 2.2.5
StyleFrame 1.3.1

Comment: @SureshK Thanks, finally managed to reproduce. See my answer.

Comment: @DeepSpace Thank you so much. I will check and let you know soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bug in StyleFrame that is caused by the fact that `[col for col in sf.columns if col.style.fill.fgColor.rgb in ('FFFFFFFF', utils.colors.white)]`  returns an empty list (ie, the condition is `False` for every column).

This will be fixed in the next version.

A temporary workaround:

```
required_cols = [col for col in sf.columns
                 if col.style.fill.fgColor.rgb in ('FFFFFFFF', utils.colors.white)]
sf = sf[required_cols] if required_cols else StyleFrame(pd.DataFrame(columns=sf.columns))
```